How can I find a positively oriented parametrization?
I need to find a parametrization of the surface defined by $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=9$, $x+y+z\geq 1$. The orientation must be compatible with the orientation of its boundary, that is, if the loop lies in the $xy$-plane then we have to choose the circulation counterclockwise and the flux upward. How can I do that?
Any hint?

You can parameterize the region with spherical coordinates,
$$(x,y,z) = (3\cos u \sin v, 3\sin u \sin v, 3\cos v) =: \vec s(u,v)$$
For $u\in[0,2\pi]$, the constraint $x+y+z\ge1$ can be used to solve for $v$ as a function of $u$,
$$\begin{align*}
& 3 (\cos u + \sin u) \sin v + 3\cos v = 1 \\
\implies & \sqrt2\,\sin\left(u+\frac\pi4\right) \sin v + \cos v = \frac13 \\
\implies & \sqrt{1+2\sin^2\left(u+\frac\pi4\right)} \sin \left(v + \arctan \frac1{\sqrt2\sin\left(u+\frac\pi4\right)}\right) = \frac13 \\
\implies & v=v(u) = 2 \arctan \left(\frac{3(\cos u+\sin u)-\sqrt{17+9\sin(2u)}}4\right)
\end{align*}$$
so that the polar angle is delimited by $v\in[0,v(u)]$.
Plot of the surface in question:

Compute the normal to the surface, and correct the sign as needed to get the right orientation.
$$\frac{\partial\vec s}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \vec s}{\partial v} = \left(-9\cos u\sin^2v, -9\sin u \sin^2v, -9\cos v\sin v\right)$$

Do you write $v$ as a function of $u$ just to delimite the polar angle? What do you mean when you say that we should correct the sign as needed? If it were necessary to correct it, how would it affect the parametrization?

Yes, but we could have just as easily solved for $u=u(v)$, then determine constant limits for $v$. The normal to the surface points either outward (away from origin) or inward, and the difference comes down to sign as a consequence of the anticommutativity of the cross product. In short, if $\vec s_u\times\vec s_v$ doesn't point in the right direction, just reverse the order and use $\vec s_v\times\vec s_u$. The choice between these two does not affect the parameterization at all.

As for deciding which order/sign/orientation is correct for this exercise, you can check the behavior of the $z$-component of the normal. It's simple enough to show that the range of $v(u)$ lies within the interval $\left[-\frac\pi2,0\right]$, and on this interval we have $-\cos v\sin v>0$. So the normal as computed here has the correct orientation.
